# Pytorch: how to mask flexible size of input for average pooling?

Tags: deep-learning, nlp, time-series, conv-neural-network, pytorch

**Backgroud**: I would like to apply convolutions and average pooling to sequences for sequence classification task.

**Problem**: without mask for inputs, the calculation of mini-batch and one-by-one will be different. 
For example:

```
# Two sequences.
s1 = torch.range(start=1, end=6).view(-1, 1)
s2 = torch.range(start=1, end=3).view(-1, 1)

##########################################
# one-by-one

# Convolutions.
kernels = torch.ones(1, 1, 2)
h1 = F.conv1d(s1.view(1, 1, -1), kernels) #h1=[[[3, 5, 7, 9, 11]]]
h2 = F.conv1d(s2.view(1, 1, -1), kernels) #h2=[[[3, 5]]]

# Average pooling.
h1 = h1.mean(-1) #h1=[[7]]
h2 = h2.mean(-1) #h2=[[4]]

##########################################
# mini-batch
s = torch.nn.utils.rnn.pad_sequence([s1, s2], batch_first=True)
s = s.permute(0, 2, 1)
h = torch.mean(F.conv1d(s, kernels), dim=-1) #h=[[7], [2.2]]
```

As you can see, the `h` is different from `[h1, h2]`.

**Questions**:

1. In order to make mini-batch the same as one-by-one, what is the normal way to employ?
2. Is there a given pytorch api?
3. If not, how to implement that?

Comment: Working with padded sequences and convolutions in pytorch is unfortunately quite painful. I usually solve these problems by writing my own masked implementations of the necessary operations (mean, std, var, ...), which is also useful for correct batch norm calculations. But having pack padded seqence work for 1D convs would be really good.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, this will not be an issue any more when pytorch convolutions and pooling operations will support packed sequence, but this is not yet the case afaik.

So, you have to deal with this yourself. There are 2 issues to deal with:

- at the right border, convolutions with padding may give more outputs than without padding
- your mean() operation will take into account padding

One possible solution would be to compute a mask tensor that masks with 0 all convolution outputs that are outside the "normal" range of outputs that you would obtain when handling your sequences one by one without padding. Thus, you may multiply this mask with the actual output of the convolutions to set all masked outputs to zero, and finally implement your own mean() operator that sums and divides by the number of unmasked timesteps.

That's not very easy to do ;-) and there may be other solutions I don't know.